# NameError: name ??? is not defined - input python 3.7.6

Tags: python, sockets, nameerror

To practice network programming I am trying to set up a client and server, the client can send a message to the server. However, when trying to get input from user on client, it gets a NameError. I looked this error up and saw it used to pop up before python 3, instead of raw_input. However, I am using python 3.7.6 so I don't understand what could be wrong. Any help is appreciated!

**Client code:**

```
import socket

SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 5050
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
SIZE = 1024
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "DISCONNECT"

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT))

text = input("Type your message:")

send(text)

send(DISCONNECT_MESSAGE)
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 18, in <module>
    text = input("(To disconnect type: 'DISCONNECT')\nType your message:")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hoi' is not defined
```

Comment: I suspect you still have Python 2.7 installed and Python 2.7 is running your script.  Try adding `import sys` and `print(sys.version)` to the top of your script and see what it prints out.

Comment: Yep you are right! Thanks a lot! I was confused as below in the screen in VS Code there was Python 3.7.6, but indeed it was actually running on python 2.7.